# object declaring keyword in javascript

Tags: javascript

What is the different between new keyword and no keyword in declaring object.

```
var person = function(){
    return {
        name: '',
        age: 0
    }
}

var mgmg = person();
var koko = new person();

mgmg.name="mg mg";
koko.name="ko ko";

alert(mgmg.name);
alert(koko.name);
```

Comment: in this case, nothing, but you're using javascript wrong

Comment: I used factory style object. Is it wrong?

Comment: your example is too simplistic to make a judgement call - the "new" keyword makes very little if any difference - see the answer provided in the duplicate